# Getting a nice form from a series of PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, summation

I had the left form and I believe I identified it to be the thing on the right:
$$\sum_{i,j=1}^n \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_j}\overset{?}{=}\nabla u \cdot \nabla v$$

But when I had:

$$\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_j}$$

Where $a_{ij}$ are just entries from an $n\times n$ matrix. Is there some way to get the below thing to a nice $\nabla$ filled form?

Comment: $\nabla u A \nabla v$?

Comment: @Thomas So then my first line is wrong, and I  believe you are right.

Answer (score 0):

$\nabla u \cdot \nabla v$ is same as
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i}
\end{equation}
The expression
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_j}
\end{equation}
is a second order tensor and therefore should be just $\nabla u \nabla v$, no dot between the two. Further,
\begin{equation}
a_{ij}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_j}
\end{equation}
can be written as $\nabla u \cdot A \cdot \nabla v$, where $A$ is a second order tensor, represented as a matrix.

Comment: Are there meant to be sums?

Comment: Yes, I have used Einstein summation convention.

Comment: Oh crêpe, I didn't see the repeated term, thanks

Comment: I don't understand the last part though, you are saying that $\nabla u \nabla v = \nabla u \cdot A \cdot \nabla v$?

Comment: @PDE, you are right, I forgot to add a_{ij} in the last formula. Thanks for pointing it out.